# Is there a way to log/record deleted documents when the retention period has come to an end?

Tags: document-library, ootb, retention

My client wants documents to be deleted after the retention period has come to an end, but would like to record/log what gets deleted for auditing purposes. Is there any way we can do this OOTB?

Any suggestions would be welcomed OOTB or otherwise :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the retention policy you can have multiple steps that can take advantage of different workflows.  For a stage you could start a workflow that creates a list item in a custom list.  You could use that custom list as a way to keep your records.  The next stage you could delete the document like you are already planning on doing.

Comment: Food for thought, thank you. Ideally we want to log the item after the document is deleted otherwise how would we know if the item had been deleted. Perhaps the deletion of the document would activate the workflow, but how would we set the item Id, Title and deleted date?

Comment: You could log it directly before it was deleted. You would know it is deleted as that would be how you set up your retention policy. It follows each stage whenever the condition is met.  Put them both on the same condition and have the log occur first.  I'm not positive about how to do this part specifically, but you can create a workflow and choose that to start as the stage in your retention policy. If you can set that workflow to create a list item you could grab any metadata you want to keep.